# Media type '' is not supported. Valid media types: [*/*]

Tags: c#

I am getting an error while inserting an image to my Google - drive account , please look at the code"Media type '' is not supported. Valid media types: [*/*]"

```
private static Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File insertFile(DriveService service, String title,  String description, String parentId, String mimeType, String filename)
{
    // File's metadata.
    Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File body = new Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();
    body.Title = "Bluehills.jpg";
    body.Description = "hello";
    body.MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk";
    //var googleFile = new google.Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File();

    // Set the parent folder.
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(parentId))
    {
        body.Parents = new List<ParentReference>() { new ParentReference() { Id = parentId } };
    }

    // File's content.
    byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);

    try
    {
        FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, mimeType);
        request.Upload();

        Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File file = request.ResponseBody;

        // Uncomment the following line to print the File ID.
        // Console.WriteLine("File ID: " + file.Id);

        return file;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"application/vnd.google-apps.drive-sdk" is used for creating shortcuts.

Try using another mime type. Like: image/jpeg

See https://developers.google.com/drive/release-notes

Comment: By using body.MimeType = "image/jpeg"; is sending the same error message

Answer (score 0):

I also found one more solution.
**Consumes Attribute**, Either remove Consumes attribute or Add as following image.
[image]