# Not supported media type when using Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I submit the set of the fields from a client side to the Web API. The fields contain both : the usual fields, like text data and also the attached file(image)
I can see the incoming data if the submission URL points to MVC's Controller
but for some strange reason I get the error "Not supported media type" if I change the URL to Web API.

Comment: You need a CustomMediaFormatter. See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38537484/post-image-to-asp-net-api-2-and-angular-2/38539120#38539120

Comment: I checked it. It contains the line: attachment.Content = await fileContents.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();  which is not quite clear in my case: The type of attachment.Content of my DTO object is HttpPostedFileBase, so it does not compile

Comment: Please post your model class here so that I can suggest accordingly

Comment: One of the reason I found, See my answer from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73621179/5532937)